# R topic model tag metadate with DublinCore

Tags: r, metadata, tm, sapply, topicmodels

I have a large volume of texts (12,000 documents with thousands of words in each), now I would like to add metadata on each of the document (date, creator, title), which is stored in a separate date frame.

The basic structure of the raw data is something like this:

```
    doc1 = "I am a student"
    doc2 = "You are a student too"
    corpus = c(list(doc1), list(doc2))
    corpus = corpus(VectorSource(corpus))
    info = data.frame(date = c(2017-01-01, 2017-01-02), creator = c("Jack", "Jone"), title = c("12331""32191")
```

What I managed to do is a loop:

```
    for (i in 1:length(corpus)){
         DublinCore(corpus[[i]], tag = "date") = info$date[i]
         DublinCore(corpus[[i]], tag = "creator") = info$creator[i]
         DublinCore(corpus[[i]], tag = "title") = info$title[i]
    }
```

Yet as I said, I have a lot of documents, and I cannot afford the inefficiency of loops. So I am thinking of using sapply function:

```
    sapply(1:length(corpus), function(x) DublinCore(corpus[[x]], tag = "date") = info$date[x])
    sapply(1:length(corpus), function(x) DublinCore(corpus[[x]], tag = "creator") = info$creator[x])
    sapply(1:length(corpus), function(x) DublinCore(corpus[[x]], tag = "title") = info$title[x])
```

What it does is that it directly print things out for me, instead of really change the metatag. However I do not know how, or where, to store the result.

I would really appreciate it if you could look into this problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's not true that `sapply()` is always faster than a loop. In fact, as long as memory allocation isn't a problem, for loop are usually faster. If this is the only reason you are doing this, you should probably reconsider.

Comment: Thank you MrFlick. But I am just wondering the reason why my sapply does not work here in general. Because this is not my first time my sapply does not give me the intended result. Thank you.

Comment: It's likely a scoping issue. Functions in R shouldn't modify variables outside their own scope. And if they try, they just create a local copy in ther own scope. You are tying to change values in `corpus` which does not exist in the function itself. `sapply` should not be called for "side-effects". It should return an object that you then use later. A `for` loop would be much more simple here.